# TensorFlow - How to read variable-length parts of data?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to read variable_length parts of data of a single file using data reader in TensorFlow.
My file is as follows: [data_length_1, data_bytes_1, data_length_2, data_bytes_2, ...]
The first byte represents the number of bytes to be read, and then this process repeats.

The problem is that I want to read data into queue in TensorFlow. I have tried [tf.FixedLengthRecordReader](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/readers#FixedLengthRecordReader) , but it accepts only fixed length data to be read. Is there any way to change it into variable-length data reader?

Comment: a work-around is to re-encode data into tf.Example records, read them as strings and do `tf.parse_example`

Comment: I have done this, but I'm looking for another approach that has no re-encoding. I appreciate any help!

Comment: an alternative approach may be to write add an op that reads variable length bytes -- https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by adding a [custom data reader](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/new_data_formats/) that reads the record length for each record from its first data byte, and it works.